# adding packages to jupyter notebook - specifically physics packages

Tags: packages

i am working with jupyter notebook, writing some homework in latex . 
lately i encountered a problem when trying to write signs from quantum mechanics (bra , ket) .

when i just write in a markdown cell the following : 
$\bar{\psi}$ . 
it doesn't recognize the \bra. i figure i should install some package for that but i am not sure how to do so .

eventually i found this [site](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/latex_envs/README.html) with instructions on installing some latex enviorments for jupyter notebook but i'm not sure it contains the physics package AND i failed to actually install it.

this is the readout of the terminal when typing

```
 pip3 install jupyter_latex_envs [--user][--upgrade]
```

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 93, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1828, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1818, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1562, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3752, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1566, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3536, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 178, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 326, in run
    self.name, wheel_cache
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 268, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 280, in install_req_from_line
    extras = Requirement("placeholder" + extras_as_string.lower()).extras
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 97, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc : e.loc + 8], e.msg
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'[--upgra'": Expected stringEnd
```

that's the error i got after trying to install via pip .

so bottom line is , i want to learn how to load a package of physics latex to jupyter notebook , and if my current attempt is actually good then i want to learn how to pass the current installation error .

- i'm using macos

Comment: Hi, welcome. The Notebook uses MathJax to render equations. MathJax is not LaTeX, so you cannot load LaTeX packages.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. are you sure? https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/physics.html

Comment: @Hyperplane Yes. There is an extension to MathJax emulating the physics package. That is not the same as loading the actual LaTeX package, which you cannot, to my knowledge,  do. (I guess I could have searched a bit though, I wasn’t aware of the extension, a link to it would have been useful to the OP, but anyways, the installation/activation is off topic here.)

Comment: Might be irrelevant at this point, but you're getting that error because you're including the `[--user][--upgrade]`. That part is just telling you about options you could use in this install. You want to just run `pip3 install jupyter_latex_envs` or `pip3 install --user jupyter_latex_envs`.